# Generic builder pattern but "type parameter is not within its bound?"

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn the builder pattern and have run into a problem with setting up the generics of it.

I was following along with [this discussion](http://www.javabyexamples.com/lets-discuss-builder-pattern) and believe I've replicated the code to my situation correctly.

My code below is stripped down (no getters/setters, etc) as they should be irrelevant to the issue I am facing.

My master abstract class is `Question`:

```
public abstract class Question{

    private StringProperty question = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
    private ObjectProperty<Object> defaultValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
    private BooleanProperty required = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private QuestionType questionType;

    public abstract String getValueEmailString();

    public Question(String question) {

        this.question.set(question);
    }

    public Question(String question,
                    String description,
                    Object defaultValue,
                    boolean required) {

        this.question.set(question);
        this.description.set(description);
        this.defaultValue.set(defaultValue);
        this.required.set(required);
    }
}
```

One implementation is the `TextQuestion` class:

```
public class TextQuestion extends Question {

    private boolean longText = false;

    public TextQuestion(String question) {

        super(question);
        setQuestionType(QuestionType.TEXT);
    }
}
```

Now I also have two more classes, an `AbstractQuestionBuilder` which is exactly what it says:

```
public abstract class AbstractQuestionBuilder<SELF extends QuestionBuilder<SELF, TTarget>,
        TTarget extends Question> implements QuestionBuilder<SELF, TTarget> {

    // **********************************************************************************************
    // Parent fields
    // **********************************************************************************************
    private String question;
    private String description;
    private Object defaultValue;
    private boolean required;
    private QuestionType questionType;

    @Override
    public SELF text(String questionText) {

        this.question = questionText;
        return self();
    }

    @Override
    public SELF description(String description) {

        this.description = description;
        return self();
    }

    @Override
    public SELF defaultValue(Object defaultValue) {

        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        return self();
    }

    @Override
    public SELF required(boolean required) {

        this.required = required;
        return self();
    }

    @Override
    public TTarget build() {

        return null;
    }

    protected abstract TTarget internalBuild();

    private SELF self() {
        return (SELF) this;
    }
}
```

Last is the `QuestionBuilders` class, which will be the main contact point for my application to build the various `Question` implementations.  This is where I am stuck:

```
public class QuestionBuilders {

    // **********************************************************************************************
    // Text Question builder
    // **********************************************************************************************
    static class TextQuestionBuilder extends AbstractQuestionBuilder<QuestionBuilder, Question> {
                                                                     ^^^^ Error is here
        private boolean longText = false;

        public TextQuestionBuilder longText(boolean longText) {

            this.longText = longText;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected Question internalBuild() {

            return null;
        }
    }

    // **********************************************************************************************
    // Abstract builder class
    // **********************************************************************************************
    abstract static class AbstractQuestionBuilder<SELF extends QuestionBuilder<SELF, TTarget>,
            TTarget extends Question> implements QuestionBuilder<SELF, TTarget> {

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Parent fields
        // **********************************************************************************************
        private String questionText;
        private String description;
        private Object defaultValue;
        private boolean required;
        private QuestionType questionType;

        @Override
        public SELF text(String questionText) {

            this.questionText = questionText;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public SELF description(String description) {

            this.description = description;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public SELF defaultValue(Object defaultValue) {

            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public SELF required(boolean required) {

            this.required = required;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public TTarget build() {

            return internalBuild();
        }

        protected abstract TTarget internalBuild();

        private SELF self() {
            return (SELF) this;
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to define the `TextQuestionBuilder`, I am getting an error I cannot make sense of:

`Type parameter 'QuestionBuilder' is not within its bound; should extend 'QuestionBuilder<QuestionBuilder,Question>'`

As far as I can tell, using `QuestionBuilder<SELF extends QuestionBuilder<SELF, TTarget>, TTarget extends Question>` should be correct.

Where am I mixed up?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `TextQuestionBuilder extends AbstractQuestionBuilder<TextQuestionBuilder, Question>`?

Comment: Hmm. Yes. Yes, it should. Thank you! I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around generics in general, and this multi-layered approach is even more confusing. I understand now that `SELF` should have actually been a reference to ... well, itself.